# Mongoid Search by Array of Association Id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid4

I have a Rails 4.2, Mongoid 4 project with these models:

```
class Customer #aka Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :branches
end

class Branch
  include Mongoid::Document  

  field :name, type: String, default: ""

  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I want to find all the Customers (aka Companies) that have a branch with name "New York". I would think that this code would work:

```
branches = Branch.where(name: "New York").map(&:_id)
=> [BSON::ObjectId('54f76cef6272790316390100')]
Customer.where(:branch_ids => branches).entries
```

However, it always returns an empty array, no matter what I try. In place of `branch_ids`, I've also tried `branches`, `branch`, `branches_id`, and others, but to no avail. I've also tried to convert the `BSON::ObjectID` to plain `string`, but that doesn't work either.

So, basically, how can I search a model based on an array of association ids? Thanks.

Comment: What does it return : `Customer.elem_match(branches: { name: "New York" })`

Comment: And this - `Customer.where(:branches.elem_match => { name: "New York" })`

Comment: @SharvyAhmed Both return an empty array (after calling `.entries`)

Comment: could you try without .entries, try .to_a at the end and let us know the output

Comment: Does it return all the customers ?

Comment: With `.to_a`, it still returns empty array. Without `.entries` or `.to_a` it returns a valid `Mongoid::Criteria`, but that in itself isn't helpful to me.

Comment: Did you try this to get the branches ids `branches = Branch.where(name: "New York").map { |b| b.id.to_s }` ? Then `Customer.where(branch_id: branches).entries` ? `branch_id` would be the field name, instead of branch_ids.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same thing with or without the `BSON::ObjectID`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72784/discussion-between-sharvy-ahmed-and-ryan-k).

Comment: do you still have desire to do it in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relations are

Customer `has_many :branches` and

Branch `belongs_to :customer`,

Then branches collection will have a `customer_id` column and not the reverse. So you can do

```
cust_ids = Branch.where(name: "New York").map(&:customer_id)
Customer.find(cust_ids)
```

Since you need only the customer ids from the first query, it is advisable to use pluck

```
cust_ids = Branch.where(name: "New York").pluck(:customer_id)
```

Comment: That does work (don't know why I didn't think of it), but it seems like a workaround. I know that there isn't a column of `branch_ids`, but there is a method. I just don't know if you can search via a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Symbol#elem_match` like this:

```
Customer.where(:branches.elem_match => { name: "New York" })
```

And `Queryable#elem_match` like this:

```
Customer.elem_match(branches: { name: "New York" })
```

Both query will give return you Customers of 'New York' branches.